# Closing one thread when another thread is closed in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a server-client application. I have three classes, namely, *Server.java, TestServer.java, Client.java.*

*TestServer* and *Client* are for testing my *Server* class.

In *Server.java* I have two functions *receiveInput* and *sendOutput* for sending and receiving messages to/from client. I'm running each two function in two separate threads.

Two functions are something like this one:

```
public void sendOutput(){
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try{
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

        while(continueRunning){
            if(!(messageToBeSent = stdIn.readLine()).equals("/exit"))
                out.writeUTF(messageToBeSent);
            }else{
                continueRunning = false;
            }
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error: sending message");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Application works fine but I want to close two threads simultaneously when I type */exit* either from client or from server.

But, for example, when I type */exit* from client, the thread which runs *receiveInput* function stops running and sets *continueRunning* variable to false. In order for other thread to stop I need to type something so that the loop runs once and the thread sees that *continueRunning* was set to false and stops running.

How can I stop one thread immediately after other is stopped?

*Hope I was clear,*

*Thanks.*

Answer (score 0):

You can make `continueRunning` a shared static & volatile variable.

Declare like so:

```
public static volatile continueRunning = true;
```

Assuming that you created it in your Server class, then you can reference the variable from the Client class like below:

```
if (Server.continueRunning) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I declared as `private static boolean continueRunning`. But my problem is here: `if(!(messageToBeSent = stdIn.readLine()).equals("/exit"))`. When this line waits for an input I need to close this thread without giving any input.

Comment: Do you have more than one thread trying to listen to the exit command?  Or are you running the client and server on two separate JVMs?  If they are one two separate JVMs (or processes) then you need to have the exiting process to send a signal to the other process to stop -- which is a whole other problem.

Comment: Yes, I have two threads and they need to close on one exit command. Like this: machine A runs server, server runs two threads, one for waiting for input (String in my app) from client, one for sending a String to client. I run my `sendOutput` function like this: `(new Thread(new Runnable(){public void run(){server.sendOutput();}})).start();`. And in the same way my `receiveInput`function. `(new Thread(new Runnable(){public void run(){server.receiveInput();}})).start();`. When I type "/exit" and press enter first thread closes. But other thread is still alive waiting for input from client.

Answer (score 0):

In server.java you should have a static variable

A static variable is one which remains of the same value across function calls.